# How to access node values from graph in JIT/infovis

Tags: javascript, jquery, infovis

I'm looking for a solution that is similar to that asked by [this question](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/s-uuGAM4q0I/discussion) - namely I want to access the numerical information of *each* label and display it via a tooltip - see the example below:

[image]

The aggregate data (the number at the top of each date column) is compiled in the source jit.js, and I don't have access to it.  I don't want to modify the source because it would take a lot of work and also prevent me from updating in the future without remodification.  Does anyone know an easy way to access the data for each label?  or perhaps the values of the `previous` and `next` nodes?